# Error Resize image in Shared hosting (Cpanel)

Tags: php, hosting, cpanel

I have a problem about resize image at hosting.
When i use function to resize image in Localhost, it's good.
But when i upload them to Cpanel. It's only work with small size picture. With bigger size(maybe 300kb), it doesn't work and doesn't 
show any errors. How to fix it?
Please help me!
Command :

```
resize_image('max',"upload/tindang/".$Hinh,"upload/tindang/".$Hinh,600,600);
```

This is my function :

```
function resize_image_crop($image,$width,$height) {
    $w = @imagesx($image); //current width
    $h = @imagesy($image); //current height
    if ((!$w) || (!$h)) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'Image couldn\'t be resized because it wasn\'t a valid image.'; return false; }
    if (($w == $width) && ($h == $height)) { return $image; } //no resizing needed

    //try max width first...
    $ratio = $width / $w;
    $new_w = $width;
    $new_h = $h * $ratio;

    //if that created an image smaller than what we wanted, try the other way
    if ($new_h < $height) {
        $ratio = $height / $h;
        $new_h = $height;
        $new_w = $w * $ratio;
    }

    $image2 = imagecreatetruecolor ($new_w, $new_h);
    imagecopyresampled($image2,$image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $w, $h);

    //check to see if cropping needs to happen
    if (($new_h != $height) || ($new_w != $width)) {
        $image3 = imagecreatetruecolor ($width, $height);
        if ($new_h > $height) { //crop vertically
            $extra = $new_h - $height;
            $x = 0; //source x
            $y = round($extra / 2); //source y
            imagecopyresampled($image3,$image2, 0, 0, $x, $y, $width, $height, $width, $height);
        } else {
            $extra = $new_w - $width;
            $x = round($extra / 2); //source x
            $y = 0; //source y
            imagecopyresampled($image3,$image2, 0, 0, $x, $y, $width, $height, $width, $height);
        }
        imagedestroy($image2);
        return $image3;
    } else {
        return $image2;
    }
}

function resize_image_max($image,$max_width,$max_height) {
    $w = imagesx($image); //current width
    $h = imagesy($image); //current height
    if ((!$w) || (!$h)) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'Image couldn\'t be resized because it wasn\'t a valid image.'; return false; }

  //  if (($w <= $max_width) && ($h <= $max_height)) { return $image; } //no resizing needed

    //try max width first...
    $ratio = $max_width / $w;
    $new_w = $max_width;
    $new_h = $h * $ratio;

    //if that didn't work
    if ($new_h > $max_height) {
        $ratio = $max_height / $h;
        $new_h = $max_height;
        $new_w = $w * $ratio;
    }

    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor ($new_w, $new_h);
    imagecopyresampled($new_image,$image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $w, $h);
    return $new_image;
}

function resize_image_force($image,$width,$height) {
    $w = @imagesx($image); //current width
    $h = @imagesy($image); //current height
    if ((!$w) || (!$h)) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'Image couldn\'t be resized because it wasn\'t a valid image.'; return false; }
    if (($w == $width) && ($h == $height)) { return $image; } //no resizing needed

    $image2 = imagecreatetruecolor ($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($image2,$image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $w, $h);

    return $image2;
}

function resize_image($method,$image_loc,$new_loc,$width,$height) {
    if (!is_array(@$GLOBALS['errors'])) { $GLOBALS['errors'] = array(); }

    if (!in_array($method,array('force','max','crop'))) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'Invalid method selected.'; }

    if (!$image_loc) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'No source image location specified.'; }
    else {
        if ((substr(strtolower($image_loc),0,7) == 'http://') || (substr(strtolower($image_loc),0,7) == 'https://')) { /*don't check to see if file exists since it's not local*/ }
        elseif (!file_exists($image_loc)) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'Image source file does not exist.'; }
        $extension = strtolower(substr($image_loc,strrpos($image_loc,'.')));
        if (!in_array($extension,array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif','.bmp'))) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'Invalid source file extension!'; }
    }

    if (!$new_loc) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'No destination image location specified.'; }
    else {
        $new_extension = strtolower(substr($new_loc,strrpos($new_loc,'.')));
        if (!in_array($new_extension,array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif','.bmp'))) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'Invalid destination file extension!'; }
    }

    $width = abs(intval($width));
    if (!$width) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'No width specified!'; }

    $height = abs(intval($height));
    if (!$height) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'No height specified!'; }

    if (count($GLOBALS['errors']) > 0) { echo_errors(); return false; }

    if (in_array($extension,array('.jpg','.jpeg'))) { $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($image_loc); }
    elseif ($extension == '.png') { $image = @imagecreatefrompng($image_loc); }
    elseif ($extension == '.gif') { $image = @imagecreatefromgif($image_loc); }
    elseif ($extension == '.bmp') { $image = @imagecreatefromwbmp($image_loc); }

    if (!$image) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'Image could not be generated!'; }
    else {
        $current_width = imagesx($image);
        $current_height = imagesy($image);
        if ((!$current_width) || (!$current_height)) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'Generated image has invalid dimensions!'; }
    }
    if (count($GLOBALS['errors']) > 0) { @imagedestroy($image); echo_errors(); return false; }

    if ($method == 'force') { $new_image = resize_image_force($image,$width,$height); }
    elseif ($method == 'max') { $new_image = resize_image_max($image,$width,$height); }
    elseif ($method == 'crop') { $new_image = resize_image_crop($image,$width,$height); }

    if ((!$new_image) && (count($GLOBALS['errors'] == 0))) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'New image could not be generated!'; }
    if (count($GLOBALS['errors']) > 0) { @imagedestroy($image); echo_errors(); return false; }

    $save_error = false;
    if (in_array($extension,array('.jpg','.jpeg'))) { imagejpeg($new_image,$new_loc) or ($save_error = true); }
    elseif ($extension == '.png') { imagepng($new_image,$new_loc) or ($save_error = true); }
    elseif ($extension == '.gif') { imagegif($new_image,$new_loc) or ($save_error = true); }
    elseif ($extension == '.bmp') { imagewbmp($new_image,$new_loc) or ($save_error = true); }
    if ($save_error) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'New image could not be saved!'; }
    if (count($GLOBALS['errors']) > 0) { @imagedestroy($image); @imagedestroy($new_image); echo_errors(); return false; }

    imagedestroy($image);
    imagedestroy($new_image);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Probably a memory limit issue if it works with smaller images.